# Routing HTTP through specific network interface

Tags: linux, networking, routes, raspberry-pi, port

I'm very unfamiliar with Linux so forgive me if this has been answered before, I've read quite a few answers but I'm never sure if they actually relate to my question.

I have a headless raspberry pi that connects to my phone's bluetooth automatically, my phone shares its internet access by tethering. I use this initial and reliable connection to SSH to my raspberry pi, and use the desktop with VNC viewer.

I would like to connect to a WiFi network that uses a captive portal, but the browser always uses the bluetooth connection so it never redirects me to the portal page. The bluetooth connection is just to be able to use the desktop so I can get through the portal, then I would like to either disconnect bluetooth or just not use it, mainly because of the low bandwidth it provides.

I've added wlan0 as a priority interface with ifmetric, but that hasn't worked.

I was thinking that forcing all HTTP connections through the wlan0 interface could solve the problem, but there may be a simpler way, feel free to tell me.

Can you explain in "simple" terms the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are multiple solutions. The simplest is making sure that there is only one correct default route.

There are 3 situations:

1. You are only connected via bluetooth via ssh
2. You are connected via bluetooth and via wifi, but not yet through the splash
3. You are through the splash

Each will require a different network configuration.

In 1, your network config will probably be:

- some IP address (let's call it IP-bt) and network mask
- Default gateway is your phone

With `route -n` you can verify this.

In 2, the network config will depend a bit on the wifi network, but in general, your network config will be:

- you'll still have IP-bt
- you will have a new address on the wifi adapter (which we call IP-wifi)
- the default gateway should be the gateway on the wifi network.

When you verify this with `route -n`, you might still see a route with destination 0.0.0.0 towards your phone. You can delete this route. Your phone should be on a directly connected network and your ssh session should therefore not break.

If the default gw is not on the wifi network, you can still remove the route that sets your phone as default gw.

Under 3, the default gw must be on the wifi network, and not on the phone. You will still be able to use your phone, because it is directly connected.

Something to watch out for in this scenario is that your phone will act as a DHCP server. That means once in a while your DHCP lease will refresh, and the bluetooth default route may re-appear. Disconnecting bluetooth will prevent this.

The second solution is to use `ifmetric`. Instead of making `wlan0` a lower metric, make your bluetooth a higher metric. Again verify with `route -n` that the metrics are as you want them to be. Verify with a traceroute how the packets are moving.

A third, and most complex option would be to install Quagga and configure correct routing.

Comment: Thanks. With ifmetric I set wlan0 to 0 and bnep0 to 1, is this correct ? Because when using my browser I see no splash page.

Comment: No. Set wlan0 t0 100 and bnep0 to 150. Not zero.